# File with a short URL downloaded with original filename

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Question (*see below for longer explanations and things I have tried already*) :

**Is there a way of having the short URL http://example.com/qf56p9z redirect to the first file found on the server of the form `/files/qf56p9z_(.*)`, and having it downloaded on the client with filename = `(.*)` ?** (if possible, without PHP)

---

Background :

I have a file on server stored in `/files/qf56p9z_blahblah.xls` that I would like to be accessible from this short URL :

http://example.com/qf56p9z

(+the same for other thousands of files)

Moreover, I would like that when the user goes to this URL, the file will be downloaded on the client computer with the *original filename*, i.e. `blahblah.xls`.

*This may be possible with PHP, I tried things like (this could be easily automated for each of my thousands of files) :*

```
<?php
header('Content-type: ...');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blahblah.xls"');
readfile('qf56p9z_blahblah.xls');
?>
```

But I see two problems with this method :

- For each reading of the file by a client, PHP has to load the whole file in memory, and output the new file. This is much more CPU/memory consuming than if apache has just to send the file, without PHP
- If one day I host all those files elsewhere (on Amazon S3 for example), the file will have to do this route :

  `Distant-Hosting (AmazonS3) ==> my server/header modified with PHP ==> client`

  It is a shame that the data has to do this instead of :

  `Distant-Hosting (AmazonS3) ==> client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of **PHP** and **.htaccess** (*using mod_rewrite*)

#### Site structure

- **`/var/www/html/files/`**: directory that contains your files in
  `{prefix}_{filename}` format
- **`/var/www/html/download.php`**: PHP script to locate the first file with given prefix
- **`/var/www/html/.htaccess`**: with 2 mod_rewrite rules for rewriting the download URL

**`download.php`**

```
<?PHP

$files_dir = "files/";

if(isset($_GET['prefix'])){
    $files = glob($files_dir.$_GET['prefix']."_*");
    if(count($files) > 0) {
        $dl = strlen($files_dir);
        $pl = strlen($_GET['prefix']);
        $fn = substr($files[0], $dl+$pl+1);
        header("Location: d/".$_GET['prefix']."/".$fn);
    }
}

?>
```

This selects the first file with the required prefix and redirects to it.

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$     download.php?prefix=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^d/(.+)/(.+)$   files/$1_$2 [L]
```

The first rule rewrites the short URL to download.php and the second rule rewrites the URL  to the original file location.

**This is how it works**

1. http://example.com/qf56p9z -- **.htaccess** -> http://example.com/download.php?prefix=qf56p9z
2. download.php -- **PHP Redirect** --> http://example.com/d/qf56p9z/blahblah.xls
3. http://example.com/d/qf56p9z/blahblah.xls -- **.htaccess** --> http://example.com/files/qf56p9z_blahblah.xls

During all the above steps, browser's location bar URL remains the same without any change.

Comment: Waw! This is great. So here the PHP code only makes the redirection thing, right? PHP doesn't have to read the whole file in memory, is it right ?

Comment: Yes. PHP will only know the filename;  will not read its contents.